# Using topological tricks to prove algebraic identities with full generality

Tags: abstract-algebra, matrices, logic, field-theory

I had a vague idea that algebraic identities proved with such tricks in $\mathbb{R}, \mathbb{C}$ should hold in other rings. In other words, $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$ does not add new identities, so we can work in those fields without loss of generality.

Here are my observations:

Let $R$ be a commutative ring with identity. Let's say that we want to prove that $A\operatorname{adj}(A) = \operatorname{adj}(A)A$ for square matrices $A \in M_{n \times n}(R)$ given that $A\operatorname{adj}(A) = \det(A)I$. First we prove for $R = \mathbb{C}$. Since the set of singular matrices is Zariski closed in $\mathbb{C}^{n \times n}$ it is nowhere dense in the usual topology, thus we can assume that $A$ is nonsingular. Inverse matrices commute, so we are done. Now since the theory of algebraically closed fields of characteristic zero is complete, the identity(identities) hold in the algebraic closure of the fraction field of $\mathbb{Z}[(x_\alpha)_{\alpha<\kappa}]$, the polynomial ring in $\kappa$ indeterminates over $\mathbb{Z}$, where $\kappa$ is an arbitrary cardinal, thus a fortiori in $\mathbb{Z}[(x_\alpha)_{\alpha<\kappa}]$. Since every commutative ring with identity is a quotient ring of such polynomial rings, we gain the full generality.

Furthermore, by elementary arguments, we get $\mathbb{Z}$ has also same identities with $\mathbb{C}$. So does every commutative ring with characteristic zero.

Is this correct?

Comment: It looks OK to me. In the first part, $n$ is presumably fixed: you can't quantify over it. So I think you could give a simpler argument: any identity containing $N$ variables is true in all rings iff it is true in $\Bbb{Z}[x_1, \ldots, x_N]$ which you can embed in $\Bbb{C}$ or $\Bbb{R}$. Or am I missing something?

Comment: @RobArthan Oh, I missed it. I think that's much simpler.

Comment: Also, when you write $\mathrm{Th}_{\Pi_1}(R)$ do you mean identities that hold in $R$ or arbitrary $\Pi_1$ formulas that hold in $R$? I don't think what you say is right if you mean the latter: e.g., $\forall x, y(x^2 = 2 \Rightarrow x = y)$ is true in $\Bbb{Z}$ or $\Bbb{Q}$, but not in $\Bbb{R}$ or $\Bbb{C}$.

Comment: @RobArthan Edited my post. Thanks

Comment: nice question! (+1) this is reminiscent to me of the proof of the generalized Cayley-Hamilton theorem; first show that it holds over algebraically closed fields, then over integral domains (by embedding the domain into the algebraic closure of its fraction field), and then over arbitrary rings (by considering a suitable quotient of a polynomial ring over $\mathbb{Z}$)